# Performance degrading while using stored procedure in place of SQL query in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, database-performance

To improve the performance of my report in terms of time taken by it to load I want to change the source from direct query to stored procedure but using stored procedure is taking more time.

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    *,
    YEAR(DT_DATE) YEAR1,
    DATENAME(mm, DT_DATE) Month1,
    CAST([Original Service Line TCV] AS float) OSL_TCV,
    CAST([BB12] AS decimal) BB12_new 
FROM
    T_OPTYLINEVIEW_REP 
WHERE 
    [Selling SBU] IN (@selling_SBU) 
    AND [Selling BU] IN (@selling_BU) 
    AND [Selling MU] IN (@selling_MU) 
    AND [Stage] IN (@stage) 
    AND [Account Type] IN (@Account_Type) 
    AND [Business Line] IN (@Business_Line) 
    AND [Business Line Level 1] IN (@Business_Line_Level_1) 
    AND [Business Line Level 2] IN (@Business_Line_Level_2) 
    AND [Offer] IN (@Offer)
    AND [Sector] IN (@Sector) 
    AND [Portfolio] IN (@Portfolio) 
    AND [flag Altran Collaboration] IN (@flag_Altran_Collaboration) 
    AND [Selling Reporting Unit] IN (@Selling_Reporting_Unit) 
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, DT_TECH_UPD, 103) = CONVERT( VARCHAR, @ReportAsOn, 103)
```

I am putting this query directly into SSRS.For this if I see the retrieval time in report server executionlog it is taking around 11000 ms.

I converted this into stored procedure to make the processing faster->

```
[dbo].[OptyLineView_test_proc](    
@selling_SBU nvarchar(max),
@selling_BU nvarchar(max),  
@selling_MU nvarchar(max),  
@stage nvarchar(max),  
@Account_Type nvarchar(max) ,  
@Business_Line nvarchar(max),  
@Business_Line_Level_1 nvarchar(max),  
@Business_Line_Level_2 nvarchar(max),  
@Offer nvarchar(max),  
@Sector nvarchar(max),    
@Portfolio nvarchar(max),  
@flag_Altran_Collaboration nvarchar(max),  
@Selling_Reporting_Unit nvarchar(max),  
@ReportAsOn date)    
as       
select DISTINCT *,    
YEAR(DT_DATE) YEAR1,    
datename(mm,DT_DATE) Month1,    
CAST([Original Service Line TCV] as float)OSL_TCV,    
CAST([BB12] as decimal) BB12_new     
from T_OPTYLINEVIEW_REP     
where [Selling SBU] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@selling_SBU, ',')) 
and [Selling BU] in  (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@selling_BU, ','))    
and [Selling MU] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@selling_MU,','))     
and [Stage] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@stage,','))     
and [Account Type] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Account_Type,','))     
and [Business Line] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Business_Line,','))     
and [Business Line Level 1] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Business_Line_Level_1,','))    
and [Business Line Level 2] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Business_Line_Level_2,','))    
AND [Offer] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Offer,','))   
AND [Sector] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Sector,','))     
AND [Portfolio] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Portfolio,','))     
AND [flag Altran Collaboration] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@flag_Altran_Collaboration,','))    
AND [Selling Reporting Unit] in (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@Selling_Reporting_Unit,','))    
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,DT_TECH_UPD , 103) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ReportAsOn , 103)
```

When I use this procedure in SSRS the date retrieval time is around 100000 ms.

Why it has increased in the case of stored procedure??

Comment: Simply encapsulating a query in a stored procedure does not improve performance. Here, it seems you've made other changes (e.g. `STRING_SPLIT`). One thing to do is to ensure the column data type matches the data type of the compared column. `STRING_SPLIT` will return `nvarchar` because of your `nvarchar(MAX)` parameters so indexes might not be used efficiently.

Comment: This query looks incredibly heavy. SELECT * is generally a bad practice, unless you *truly* need every column, in which case, you should address the column names. Does your table have a PRIMARY KEY, or even an index? Those two would help the server figure out how to answer this question.

Comment: Hum, let's see: stored procedure will only make a difference for parameter sniffing, which is probably not relevant here. You now declare these lists as `nvarchar(max)` and splitting them, it's much better (both for datatype reasons and query plan) to use a Table Parameter or temp table. What the original query was doing I can only guess, but `[Selling SBU] IN (@selling_SBU)` is never going to work with a CSV list. `CONVERT(VARCHAR,DT_TECH_UPD , 103)` is not the way to compare dates, use `CONVERT(date, DT_TECH_UPD)` or better, do a proper half-open range comparison with `>= AND <` ......

Comment: .... And `SELECT *` is not helping things, certainly `DISTINCT` is going to add further unnecessary pressure to the query plan. If you want real SQL performance help here, you will have to supply the table *and index* definitions, and share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Charlieface the original query (and the SP) are being called from reporting services - `[Selling SBU] IN (@selling_SBU)` is the correct syntax for doing that - some string replacement takes place me thinks. Interesting, and here is how to use a [TVP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347610/table-valued-parameters-for-ssrs-2008).

Comment: `CONVERT(VARCHAR, DT_TECH_UPD, 103) = CONVERT( VARCHAR, @ReportAsOn, 103)` needs to go. Covert with 103 is a date format dd/mm/yyyy. Is DT_TECH_UPD a date datatype? Then you don't need to convert it. Pass a date parameter to compare to the date column.  Transformations in the where clause kills performance, forcing table scans and preventing indexes from working,